# Как узнать ip адрес клиента pjsua python

Tags: python

Подключен модуль pjsua, ip адрес сервера 192.168.0.119, ip адрес клиента 192.168.0.137.

В подключенном модуле есть класс `CallInfo`, однако максимум что я добился это использование `remote_uri`, но к сожалению это `uri`, который указал клиент, например `100@192.168.0.119`.

Как узнать ip адрес клиента, который присылает `INVITE`, или может другие параметры? (без регистрации)

Answer (score 0):

возможно это, попробуй
[srcAddress](https://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpj_1_1CallInfo.htm)

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Danis, спасибо, я в состоянии самостоятельно отредактировать в нормальный вид:):)

Comment: aleksandr barakin, вопрос не достаточно развернут, что бы дать более развернутый ответ.

Comment: @Roman Разверните, это же ваш вопрос. Потом разверните ответ.